# How to create IP table Firewall rules for SIP calling based on user agents

Tags: python, bash, unix

I need to block a name containing user-agents, coming after a certain period of time using IP table.

Example of user agents

```
38 User-Agent: Linksys-SPA942
23 User-Agent: assdaxzxccbvcnbxcbzxvssmnnsbscbsdds
10 User-Agent: pplsip
```

I tried

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -P udp -dport 5060 -m recent --set --update --second 600 --hitcount 8 --rttl -name SSH -j DROP
```

but It will just block any UDP traffic on 5060 from some unique IP address that exceeds 8 hits in 600 seconds
but I need  table to be automatically update based of user agant.

Comment: `iptables` looks at the IP layer, not the HTTP layer.  The user-agent is contained inside HTTP requests.  Therefore `iptables` is not the tool for that.  A proxy could do this.

Comment: @Nic3500 but what if we use ```-- string "regex expression" --algobm -icase -check -second 500 -hitcount 5 -j DROP```

Comment: I do not know the entire scope of possibilities with `iptables`.  This is why I did not put it in an answer, but in comments.